# An elementary inequality of real calculus

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

It is clear that $|x+y|^2\le 2(|x|^2+|y|^2)$ as well as $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$, so I was wondering whether one may substitute 2 or 1 by some general real number $p$.

Playing around a bit with maple I have got some evidence that
$$|x+y|^p\le 2^{p-1}(|x|^p+|y|^p)\qquad \hbox{for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$  and all }p\in [1,\infty)$$

Is this inequality true? Do you have a reference for it? Does it have a name?

EDIT: I have dropped one inequality, as it was less sharp than the other in its range of validity

Comment: This is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) for the convex function $|x|^p$ at $(x+y)/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards the second one, by [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure),
$$1\cdot |x|+1\cdot |y|\leq (1^q+1^q)^{1/q}\cdot (|x|^p+ |y|^p)^{1/p}$$
where $p,q> 1$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ (that is $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{p-1}{p}$).

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is even stronger than my own inequality!